# How can I prevent jQuery from firing when the back button is pressed?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm setting the value of a textbox with jQuery to use a server side value.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txthash").val("@ViewBag.HashCode");
</script>
```

This works, however it also fires when the user presses the back button. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? I want the textbox to be filled only if there wasn't a value there to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"I want the textbox to be filled only if there wasnt a value there to begin with."* I suggest using that logic to decide whether or not you want to populate it.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $txthash = $("#txthash");
        if ($txthash.val() == "") {
            $txthash.val("@ViewBag.HashCode");
        }
    });
</script>
```